# Converting pandas dataframe into smaller pieces

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe: `denver_grouped` which has a `Neighborhood` column.  The  `Neighborhood` column has rows of neighborhoods with dozens of onehot columns for the quantity of each venue type that are in that neighborhood.  My question:  rather than print out a list in the console, how do I modify the input code to produce each `Neighborhood` as its own individual dataframe.  I would like to be able to `.describe()` each output rather than just see it in the console.  Any suggestions?

Input Code:

```
num_top_venues = 5

for hood in denver_grouped['Neighborhood']:
    print("----"+hood+"----")
    temp = denver_grouped[denver_grouped['Neighborhood'] == hood].T.reset_index()
    temp.columns = ['venue','freq']
    temp = temp.iloc[1:]
    temp['freq'] = temp['freq'].astype(float)
    temp = temp.round({'freq': 2})
    print(temp.sort_values('freq', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True).head(num_top_venues))
    print('\n')
```

Output:

```py
----Auraria----
                 venue  freq
0  American Restaurant  0.05
1                Hotel  0.05
2          Coffee Shop  0.05
3   Mexican Restaurant  0.03
4              Brewery  0.03


----Bear Valley----
         venue  freq
0         Park  0.50
1         Pool  0.25
2       Office  0.25
3  Zoo Exhibit  0.00
4   Nail Salon  0.00


----Berkeley----
            venue  freq
0         Brewery  0.07
1     Coffee Shop  0.07
2            Park  0.06
3  Breakfast Spot  0.04
4     Pizza Place  0.04


----Chaffee Park----
                  venue  freq
0  Fast Food Restaurant  0.16
1     Convenience Store  0.10
2                  Park  0.06
3          Intersection  0.06
4        Discount Store  0.06
```

etc....

complete notebook at:  https://github.com/Sageston/Coursera_Capstone/blob/main/copy-capstone.ipynb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting your `denver_grouped` DataFrame into a list of DataFrames with 1 row each using [array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy-array-split) from numpy.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Split every row into own frame
dfs = np.array_split(denver_grouped, len(denver_grouped))

# Display First Two For Reference
for df in dfs[:2]:
    print(df.to_string())
    print('---------------------')
```

Output:

```
  Neighborhood  Zoo Exhibit  ATM  Accessories Store  Alternative Healer  American Restaurant  Animal Shelter  Antique Shop  Aquarium  Arcade  Argentinian Restaurant  Art Gallery  Art Museum  Arts & Crafts Store  Asian Restaurant  Athletics & Sports  Auto Garage  Automotive Shop  BBQ Joint  Bagel Shop  Bakery  Bank   Bar  Baseball Field  Baseball Stadium  Basketball Stadium  Bed & Breakfast  Beer Garden  Beer Store  Big Box Store  Bike Rental / Bike Share  Bike Shop  Bistro  Board Shop  Bookstore  Botanical Garden  Boutique  Brazilian Restaurant  Breakfast Spot  Brewery  Bridal Shop  Bridge  Burger Joint  Burrito Place  Bus Station  Bus Stop  Butcher  Cafeteria  Café  Cajun / Creole Restaurant  Candy Store  Car Wash  Cheese Shop  Chinese Restaurant  Church  Churrascaria  Clothing Store  Cocktail Bar  Coffee Shop  Comedy Club  Concert Hall  Construction & Landscaping  Convenience Store  Cosmetics Shop  Creperie  Cuban Restaurant  Cupcake Shop  Cycle Studio  Dance Studio  Deli / Bodega  Department Store  Dessert Shop  Dim Sum Restaurant  Diner  Discount Store  Dive Bar  Doctor's Office  Dog Run  Donut Shop  Dry Cleaner  Electronics Store  Empanada Restaurant  Ethiopian Restaurant  Event Space  Eye Doctor  Factory  Farmers Market  Fast Food Restaurant  Fish & Chips Shop  Fish Market  Flea Market  Flower Shop  Food  Food & Drink Shop  Food Court  Food Service  Food Stand  Food Truck  Football Stadium  French Restaurant  Fried Chicken Joint  Frozen Yogurt Shop  Furniture / Home Store  Gas Station  Gastropub  Gay Bar  General Entertainment  German Restaurant  Gift Shop  Golf Course  Gourmet Shop  Greek Restaurant  Grocery Store   Gym  Gym / Fitness Center  Gym Pool  Gymnastics Gym  Hardware Store  Hawaiian Restaurant  Health & Beauty Service  Health Food Store  History Museum  Hobby Shop  Hockey Arena  Hookah Bar  Hospital  Hot Dog Joint  Hotel  Ice Cream Shop  Indian Restaurant  Indie Movie Theater  Indie Theater  Intersection  Irish Pub  Israeli Restaurant  Italian Restaurant  Japanese Restaurant  Jazz Club  Jewelry Store  Juice Bar  Karaoke Bar  Kids Store  Kitchen Supply Store  Korean Restaurant  Lake  Latin American Restaurant  Laundry Service  Light Rail Station  Liquor Store  Lounge  Marijuana Dispensary  Market  Martial Arts School  Massage Studio  Mediterranean Restaurant  Mexican Restaurant  Miscellaneous Shop  Mobile Phone Shop  Motel  Movie Theater  Museum  Music Venue  Nail Salon  New American Restaurant  Nightclub  Noodle House  Office  Optical Shop  Organic Grocery  Other Repair Shop  Outdoor Supply Store  Paper / Office Supplies Store  Park  Performing Arts Venue  Pet Café  Pet Store  Pharmacy  Pizza Place  Playground  Plaza  Poke Place  Pool  Print Shop   Pub  Ramen Restaurant  Recreation Center  Rental Car Location  Restaurant  Rock Club  Roof Deck  Salad Place  Salon / Barbershop  Sandwich Place  Sculpture Garden  Seafood Restaurant  Shipping Store  Shoe Store  Shop & Service  Shopping Mall  Shopping Plaza  Smoke Shop  South American Restaurant  Southern / Soul Food Restaurant   Spa  Sporting Goods Shop  Sports Bar  Steakhouse  Storage Facility  Supermarket  Supplement Shop  Sushi Restaurant  Taco Place  Tailor Shop  Tanning Salon  Tapas Restaurant  Tea Room  Tennis Court  Thai Restaurant  Theater  Theme Park  Theme Park Ride / Attraction  Toy / Game Store  Trade School  Trail  Train Station  Used Bookstore  Vegetarian / Vegan Restaurant  Video Game Store  Video Store  Vietnamese Restaurant  Warehouse Store  Wine Bar  Wine Shop  Winery  Wings Joint  Women's Store  Yoga Studio
0      Auraria          0.0  0.0                0.0                0.01                 0.05             0.0           0.0      0.01     0.0                     0.0          0.0        0.01                  0.0              0.01                 0.0          0.0              0.0       0.01         0.0     0.0   0.0  0.02             0.0               0.0                0.01              0.0          0.0         0.0            0.0                       0.0       0.01     0.0         0.0       0.01               0.0       0.0                   0.0            0.01     0.03          0.0    0.01          0.01            0.0          0.0       0.0      0.0        0.0  0.02                        0.0         0.01       0.0          0.0                0.01     0.0          0.01            0.01          0.02         0.05          0.0           0.0                         0.0                0.0             0.0       0.0               0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0            0.0               0.0          0.01                 0.0    0.0             0.0       0.0              0.0      0.0         0.0          0.0                0.0                  0.0                   0.0          0.0         0.0      0.0             0.0                   0.0                0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0   0.0                0.0         0.0           0.0         0.0         0.0               0.0               0.02                  0.0                 0.0                     0.0          0.0       0.01      0.0                    0.0               0.01        0.0          0.0          0.01               0.0           0.01  0.02                   0.0       0.0             0.0             0.0                 0.01                      0.0                0.0             0.0         0.0           0.0         0.0       0.0            0.0   0.05            0.01                0.0                  0.0            0.0           0.0       0.01                 0.0                0.02                 0.01        0.0            0.0       0.01          0.0         0.0                   0.0                0.0   0.0                        0.0              0.0                 0.0           0.0    0.01                   0.0     0.0                  0.0             0.0                      0.01                0.03                 0.0                0.0    0.0            0.0    0.01          0.0         0.0                     0.03        0.0           0.0     0.0           0.0              0.0                0.0                   0.0                            0.0  0.03                   0.01       0.0        0.0       0.0         0.02         0.0   0.01        0.01   0.0         0.0  0.01               0.0                0.0                  0.0        0.03        0.0        0.0          0.0                0.01            0.01               0.0                0.03             0.0         0.0             0.0            0.0            0.01         0.0                        0.0                             0.01  0.01                 0.01         0.0        0.01               0.0          0.0              0.0              0.03         0.0          0.0           0.01               0.0      0.01           0.0             0.01      0.0        0.01                          0.02               0.0           0.0   0.01           0.01             0.0                            0.0               0.0          0.0                    0.0              0.0      0.02        0.0     0.0          0.0            0.0         0.01
---------------------
  Neighborhood  Zoo Exhibit  ATM  Accessories Store  Alternative Healer  American Restaurant  Animal Shelter  Antique Shop  Aquarium  Arcade  Argentinian Restaurant  Art Gallery  Art Museum  Arts & Crafts Store  Asian Restaurant  Athletics & Sports  Auto Garage  Automotive Shop  BBQ Joint  Bagel Shop  Bakery  Bank  Bar  Baseball Field  Baseball Stadium  Basketball Stadium  Bed & Breakfast  Beer Garden  Beer Store  Big Box Store  Bike Rental / Bike Share  Bike Shop  Bistro  Board Shop  Bookstore  Botanical Garden  Boutique  Brazilian Restaurant  Breakfast Spot  Brewery  Bridal Shop  Bridge  Burger Joint  Burrito Place  Bus Station  Bus Stop  Butcher  Cafeteria  Café  Cajun / Creole Restaurant  Candy Store  Car Wash  Cheese Shop  Chinese Restaurant  Church  Churrascaria  Clothing Store  Cocktail Bar  Coffee Shop  Comedy Club  Concert Hall  Construction & Landscaping  Convenience Store  Cosmetics Shop  Creperie  Cuban Restaurant  Cupcake Shop  Cycle Studio  Dance Studio  Deli / Bodega  Department Store  Dessert Shop  Dim Sum Restaurant  Diner  Discount Store  Dive Bar  Doctor's Office  Dog Run  Donut Shop  Dry Cleaner  Electronics Store  Empanada Restaurant  Ethiopian Restaurant  Event Space  Eye Doctor  Factory  Farmers Market  Fast Food Restaurant  Fish & Chips Shop  Fish Market  Flea Market  Flower Shop  Food  Food & Drink Shop  Food Court  Food Service  Food Stand  Food Truck  Football Stadium  French Restaurant  Fried Chicken Joint  Frozen Yogurt Shop  Furniture / Home Store  Gas Station  Gastropub  Gay Bar  General Entertainment  German Restaurant  Gift Shop  Golf Course  Gourmet Shop  Greek Restaurant  Grocery Store  Gym  Gym / Fitness Center  Gym Pool  Gymnastics Gym  Hardware Store  Hawaiian Restaurant  Health & Beauty Service  Health Food Store  History Museum  Hobby Shop  Hockey Arena  Hookah Bar  Hospital  Hot Dog Joint  Hotel  Ice Cream Shop  Indian Restaurant  Indie Movie Theater  Indie Theater  Intersection  Irish Pub  Israeli Restaurant  Italian Restaurant  Japanese Restaurant  Jazz Club  Jewelry Store  Juice Bar  Karaoke Bar  Kids Store  Kitchen Supply Store  Korean Restaurant  Lake  Latin American Restaurant  Laundry Service  Light Rail Station  Liquor Store  Lounge  Marijuana Dispensary  Market  Martial Arts School  Massage Studio  Mediterranean Restaurant  Mexican Restaurant  Miscellaneous Shop  Mobile Phone Shop  Motel  Movie Theater  Museum  Music Venue  Nail Salon  New American Restaurant  Nightclub  Noodle House  Office  Optical Shop  Organic Grocery  Other Repair Shop  Outdoor Supply Store  Paper / Office Supplies Store  Park  Performing Arts Venue  Pet Café  Pet Store  Pharmacy  Pizza Place  Playground  Plaza  Poke Place  Pool  Print Shop  Pub  Ramen Restaurant  Recreation Center  Rental Car Location  Restaurant  Rock Club  Roof Deck  Salad Place  Salon / Barbershop  Sandwich Place  Sculpture Garden  Seafood Restaurant  Shipping Store  Shoe Store  Shop & Service  Shopping Mall  Shopping Plaza  Smoke Shop  South American Restaurant  Southern / Soul Food Restaurant  Spa  Sporting Goods Shop  Sports Bar  Steakhouse  Storage Facility  Supermarket  Supplement Shop  Sushi Restaurant  Taco Place  Tailor Shop  Tanning Salon  Tapas Restaurant  Tea Room  Tennis Court  Thai Restaurant  Theater  Theme Park  Theme Park Ride / Attraction  Toy / Game Store  Trade School  Trail  Train Station  Used Bookstore  Vegetarian / Vegan Restaurant  Video Game Store  Video Store  Vietnamese Restaurant  Warehouse Store  Wine Bar  Wine Shop  Winery  Wings Joint  Women's Store  Yoga Studio
1  Bear Valley          0.0  0.0                0.0                 0.0                  0.0             0.0           0.0       0.0     0.0                     0.0          0.0         0.0                  0.0               0.0                 0.0          0.0              0.0        0.0         0.0     0.0   0.0  0.0             0.0               0.0                 0.0              0.0          0.0         0.0            0.0                       0.0        0.0     0.0         0.0        0.0               0.0       0.0                   0.0             0.0      0.0          0.0     0.0           0.0            0.0          0.0       0.0      0.0        0.0   0.0                        0.0          0.0       0.0          0.0                 0.0     0.0           0.0             0.0           0.0          0.0          0.0           0.0                         0.0                0.0             0.0       0.0               0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0            0.0               0.0           0.0                 0.0    0.0             0.0       0.0              0.0      0.0         0.0          0.0                0.0                  0.0                   0.0          0.0         0.0      0.0             0.0                   0.0                0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0   0.0                0.0         0.0           0.0         0.0         0.0               0.0                0.0                  0.0                 0.0                     0.0          0.0        0.0      0.0                    0.0                0.0        0.0          0.0           0.0               0.0            0.0  0.0                   0.0       0.0             0.0             0.0                  0.0                      0.0                0.0             0.0         0.0           0.0         0.0       0.0            0.0    0.0             0.0                0.0                  0.0            0.0           0.0        0.0                 0.0                 0.0                  0.0        0.0            0.0        0.0          0.0         0.0                   0.0                0.0   0.0                        0.0              0.0                 0.0           0.0     0.0                   0.0     0.0                  0.0             0.0                       0.0                 0.0                 0.0                0.0    0.0            0.0     0.0          0.0         0.0                      0.0        0.0           0.0    0.25           0.0              0.0                0.0                   0.0                            0.0   0.5                    0.0       0.0        0.0       0.0          0.0         0.0    0.0         0.0  0.25         0.0  0.0               0.0                0.0                  0.0         0.0        0.0        0.0          0.0                 0.0             0.0               0.0                 0.0             0.0         0.0             0.0            0.0             0.0         0.0                        0.0                              0.0  0.0                  0.0         0.0         0.0               0.0          0.0              0.0               0.0         0.0          0.0            0.0               0.0       0.0           0.0              0.0      0.0         0.0                           0.0               0.0           0.0    0.0            0.0             0.0                            0.0               0.0          0.0                    0.0              0.0       0.0        0.0     0.0          0.0            0.0          0.0
---------------------
```

---

Then do whatever computations on each "Neighborhood" df.

```py
num_top_venues = 5
# Display First Two For Reference
for df in dfs[:2]:
    print("----" + df['Neighborhood'].iloc[0] + "----")
    # Transpose Excluding Neighborhood Column
    df = df[df.columns[1:]].T.reset_index()

    df.columns = ['venue', 'freq']
    df['freq'] = df['freq'].astype(float)

    df = df.round({'freq': 2}) \
        .sort_values('freq', ascending=False) \
        .reset_index(drop=True) \
        .head(num_top_venues)

    print(df, end='\n\n')
```

Output:

```
----Auraria----
                 venue  freq
0  American Restaurant  0.05
1                Hotel  0.05
2          Coffee Shop  0.05
3   Mexican Restaurant  0.03
4              Brewery  0.03

----Bear Valley----
         venue  freq
0         Park  0.50
1         Pool  0.25
2       Office  0.25
3  Zoo Exhibit  0.00
4   Nail Salon  0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

**Two methods:**

**First method is**
that we can create a dict of newly created dfs for each separate `Neighborhood`

```
dfs = {} ## dict of all newly created dfs

for df_name, df_val in df.groupby("Neighborhood"):
    df_name = df_name.replace(' ', '_')
    dfs[df_name] = df_val

## To check the output
    for k, v in dfs.items():
        print("Name:", k)
        print(v)
```

**Second method is:**
We can fetch each `unique Neighborhood` and can apply exec to create df for it.

PS. Since few `Neighborhood` have space in the name so the newly created df will have underscore `_` in df name like `Cherry_Creek` will be the newly created df.

```
for i in df.Neighborhood.unique():
    exec(f"{i.replace(' ','_')} = df[df['Neighborhood'] == i]")
```

**Input**

```
    Borough Neighborhood    Latitude    Longitude
0   River North Auraria 39.7506 -105.0075
1   Capitol Hill    Cherry Creek    39.7195 -104.9481
2   Capitol Hill    Congress Park   39.7329 -104.9494
3   Lakeside    West Highland   39.7647 -105.0407
4   Lakeside    Sloan Lake  39.7486 -105.0473
```

**Output**.
Newly created dfs:

Auraria

```
    Borough     Neighborhood    Latitude    Longitude
0   River North Auraria         39.7506 -105.0075
```

Cherry_Creek

```
    Borough Neighborhood    Latitude    Longitude
1   Capitol Hill    Cherry Creek    39.7195 -104.9481
```

Comment: Huzzah! Your solution answered my question exactly. I am still having a little trouble though: I was hoping when I ran .describe() on the neighborhood's individual data frame that it would give a count of the quantity of each venue within every category type. Instead, it seems to be giving a count of the venue categories. Do you know how I would obtain the quantity in each category, not simply a count of "1" for each category?